# Resoldering charger cable

Tags: charging

My tab (Samsun Galaxy Tab 2) has a 30 pin to USB cable (similar to old apple cable).

I had soldered the wires a while back because the wire broke. Recently I decided to resolder them and now there is something wrong with it, now the moment I plug the charger it turns to 100% in a matter of seconds.I have taken good care to solder the Red Green White Black wires to the right place. Have I gone wrong somewhere?

Edit: It seems that the green and white cable have a short between them when I connect it to my tab , is that normal?

Here is the dmesg output if that helps

[image: dmesg output]

Comment: Most USB cables have only 4 wires (< USB 3.0).  Faster ones have more (>= USB 3.0).  But I do not think any have 30.  Are you talking about an old Apple 30 pin port?  I think there are some USB pins in that port but most of that port is for sound, video, legacy power and control.

Comment: Yup 30 pin port on one side (of which only 4 are connected) and USB on the other

Comment: I think Apple cables from that era did not have DRM chips.  So I think you only need to test the 4 USB wires for conductivity.  I am not down voting you but have noticed the score.  A good stack exchange question is clear, has a single goal, might have pictures or diagrams.  Your question needs to be edited.  At the very least, you need to state that this is an older 30 pin Apple USB cable you are having problems with.  Try to remember you need to edit your question to make it easy for others with the same problem to find your question and use the answers you receive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have incorporated that in the OP. It seems that the green and white cable have a sort between them when i connect it to my tab , is that normal?

Comment: I can only guess at this point.  Please keep that in mind when considering your next steps.  Usually a USB cable has 4 wires.  Black might be ground, red might be +5 volts, green and white might be the balanced pair for data communications and might be labeled D+ and D-.  When not plugged into anything at either end, data wires are unlikely shorted together as this would prevent communication.

Comment: Hi! Over from Android AE (Just seen this in chat, thanks Nick!) And it seems to be a software issue. I say seems because I tried replicating this an had no issues, and e first line suggests batterystats.bin is broken.

Comment: Alright! Its migrated. See my above comment on why I asked for that close to be overturned, then migrated here. Now, what OS are you using? Its pretty clear to me that its not running stock.

Comment: Ah cleared batterystats.bin and it seems to be all right now, thanks. Would you mind adding it as an answer .

Comment: Done! Just accept it when ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Ah, The Tab 2.

I've hit this problem more times than I want to count. It's an easy fix though- Just empty out batterystats.bin and plug it back in. Should be fine!